# Use Windows 2016 server with Xampp to host more than 1 website

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have tried all kinds of things, read all answers, and configured the bananas out of it, but I cannot seem to get the following working:

A windows 2016 server with XAMPP, to host more websites than 1.

What have I done:

- I have altered the httpd-vhosts.conf as described all over the web with allowing NameVirtualHost, and setting up virtual host with documentroot, servername etc.
- I have pointed a domain with the a-record to this server
- installed the latest XAMPP release to date
- changed the windows hosts file, as described everywhere (127.0.0.1 domainname.com)

What works:

- I can get the domain working on my server's browser. When I enter the specific domainname.com it shows the hello world page I made in the specified folder. The domain resolves and shows the page that is in de directory accordingly
- Besides that, the localhost of apache is also working, I have 2 sites working, but only on the browser of the server, on the machine itself.

What does not work:

Only 1 thing. when I want to access the domain from any other machine than the server (from outside so to say), it will not work, but when I ping the domain on my home-pc it resolves to the server.

I am at a loss. Been at this for hours, and beginning to question if it is even possible.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here, or if it is even possible to have more than 1 website to work on XAMPP and resolve form the outside?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have maybe same problem. Could you please take a look and help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892549/server-problem-after-windows-server-2019-update-my-domain-is-not-reachable-any

Answer (score 0):

It was windows firewall that stopped all inbound connections. I finally figured it out!